# Create list with unique value with a python list comprehension if clause not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am asked to compare 2 list and filer out unique value in a third list.
I must ensure that the third list only contains unique values, no doubles.

Following code works :

```
import os, random

def makerange(number):
    lijst = [random.randint(1,number) for item in
    range(1,random.randint(2,number))]
    return lijst

a = makerange(20)
b = makerange(20)
c = set()

for item in a:
  if item in b and item not in c:
      c.add(item)
```

I've tried to rewrite the for loop to a python list comprehension.

```
c = [ item for item in a if (item in b) & (item not in c)]
```

However this list comprehension does not work ? 
Any suggestions why this is not working ? And how should i write this with a list comprehension.

Comment: Use `and` instead of `&`. This is Python.

Comment: Your checks for **item not in c** don't do anything.  Sets keep only unique elements.

Comment: The list comprehension is evaluated completely (with `c=set()`) and then assigned to `c` (which then becomes a list)

Answer (score 5):

Your code can't work because you can't refer to `c`, because it won't exist until the comprehension has completed.

You also used the wrong operator; you need to use `and`, not `&`; the latter is a *bitwise* operation, not a boolean logic AND. It *happens* to give you the same results here, but that's just luck.

The following works, using a *set* comprehension to produce unique values:

```
c = {item for item in a if item in b}
```

or, if you *must* use a list comprehension, use a separate set to track what values you already processed; trick taken from [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order):

```
seen = set()
c = [item for item in a if item in b and not (item in seen or seen.add(item))]
```

but you may as well use a set operation, in your case *intersection*:

```
c = set(a).intersection(b)
```

or using the `&` operator, which is overloaded for sets to produce an intersection too:

```
c = set(a) & set(b)
```

Demo (with non-random values to make it easier to reproduce):

```
>>> a = [17, 8, 19, 17, 17, 4, 8, 17, 6, 19, 18, 11, 15, 8]
>>> b = [8, 9, 16, 7, 16, 14, 3, 19, 1, 17, 8, 11]
>>> {item for item in a if item in b and item not in c}
set([8, 17, 19, 11])
>>> set(a) & set(b)
set([8, 17, 11, 19])
>>> seen = set()
>>> [item for item in a if item in b and not (item in seen or seen.add(item))]
[17, 8, 19, 11]
```

Comment: Technically, since both arguments to `&` are `bool`, and `bool` values are just subclasses of `int` with numeric value 1 (`True`) and 0 (`False`), the code is accidentally correct even though it uses `&` when it should use `and`. It won't short-circuit properly, but it should work; it's not going to get different results as a result of the mistake.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, the truthy value happens to be the same *in this case*. But best to point out the correct way, lest they try to use it without boolean operators on both sides.

Comment: Agreed. Pointing it out as bad code is a good thing. It's just not "a reason it doesn't work". It doesn't work because it's trying to use `c` before `c` is bound correctly.

Comment: Reworked the ordering there; you are right it can't rightfully be listed as a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `intersection` for set instead!

```
c = set(a).intersection(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does one version of the job for you.  Turn a and b into sets and take their intersection.  Sets, by definition, contain no duplicates.  The original doesn't work for the reason several others pointed out: **&** is the wrong operator in Python.

```
a = makerange(20)
b = makerange(20)
c = set(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```

Output:

```
set([20])
```

Comment: The original working code produces an *intersection*, not a union. You also haven't addressed why the original code doesn't work.

Comment: The `&` operator is indeed wrong, but it *happens to work* when using it on two boolean values (as they do here). The reason the code fails has far more to do with the fact that `c` is not defined until the list comp completes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you only want to add items to C if and only if they are in both A and B.

```
import os, random


def makerange(number):
    lijst = [random.randint(1, number) for _ in range(1, random.randint(2, number))]
    return lijst

a, b = makerange(20), makerange(20)
c = {item for item in a if item in b} # Set comprehension
print(c)
```

You can also use an intersection of the set:

```
c = list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```